# ASP.NET Core MVC: why the content of wwwroot directory wasn't copied?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Visual Studio 2017 (v15.4.4)
ASP.NET Core MVC

I created new ASP.NET Core Web Application from the empty template and filled it. But when I start debugging I see that my CSS-file is not accessible.

> The page for the web address was not found *http://localhost:51308/css/styles.css*
>   HTTP ERROR 404

Why does it happen and how can I solve this problem?

**styles.css**:

```
.field-validation-error {color: #f00;}
.field-validation-valid {display: none;}
.input-validation-error {border: 1px solid #f00; background-color: #fee;}
.validation-summary-errors {font-weight: bold; color: #f00;}
.validation-summary-valid {display: none;}
```

**RsvpForm.cshtml**:

```
@model Razor.Models.GuestResponse
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Razor

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>RSVP Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/styles.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        This is RSVP form.
        <form asp-action="RsvpForm" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
            <p>
                <label asp-for="Name">Your name:</label>
                <input asp-for="Name" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label asp-for="Email">Your email:</label>
                <input asp-for="Email" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label asp-for="Phone">Your phone:</label>
                <input asp-for="Phone" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Will you attend?</label>
                <select asp-for="WillAttend">
                    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
                    <option value="true">Yes I'll be there</option>
                    <option value="false">No, I can't come</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <button type="submit">Submit RSVP</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

**UPD**

I renamed `styles.css` to `site.css` and shared this example on GitHub: [here](https://github.com/Andrey-Bushman/asp-net-core-sandbox) is the code source of this example.

Comment: What do you see in your browser console? maybe your path is not right.

Comment: In console I see the message: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of styles.css 404 (Not Found)`.

Comment: Depending on the provided code from Github, you must comment out the `app.UseStaticFiles();` line in order to use the `wwwroot` folder for static files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 problems.

1. You have deactivcated loading static files in your startup.cs Uncomment `app.UseStaticFiles();` This is essential in loading javascript, css, html and other static files as images from your wwwroot folder.
2. You should properly resolve your static file in your razor view, using `@Url.Content()`:  `<link href="@Url.Content("~/css/site.css")" rel="stylesheet" />`
   Just using "~/css/site.css" may work, but will not 100% of the time. I strongly recommend using a shared Layout.cshtml, that takes over loading the css files for you.

This will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

1. You must put all the fixed files like `css`, `JQuery`, `js` and ... in the `wwwroot` folder to Access it. This is a law in Asp.Net Core.
2. Also, when you run your project, hit the ctrl + U to display your code and click on the css link. The css commands must be displayed. Apeer was not displayed after a click The files are not loaded correctly.
3. By default, there is a file named `site.css`, which you must write all the css commands and your site style there. It linked in the `_Layout`, you can link your new css file after that.
4. To link up, just drag the css file from the `solution Explorer` and drop it in the code box

There is no other case

Comment: But my CSS -file already is located in the `wwwroot/css/` directory. I showed it on my screen on the topic.

Comment: @AndreyBushman I edited my answer. Please read and announce the result.

Comment: >  *The css commands must be displayed. Apeer was not displayed after a click The files are not loaded correctly.* I tried it before I created the topic. It can't find my CSS-file. I wrote about it on the topic.

Comment: I added the **UPD** section with the link to my code sources. It doesn't work :(((

Comment: @AndreyBushman I listed the important items for file linking. Your codes are not bad either. Possible shapes are coming from other parts of the project

Comment: It is a single project of my solution.

Comment: @AndreyBushman It is a custom to write styles within `site.css` file. Try to follow the same.

Comment: I did it in the code sources that I shared on GitHub on this topic. But it doesn't help.